# Grails glink optional params attribute not filtered based on custom urlMappings

Tags: grails, hyperlink, parameters, url-mapping

Using the custom url mappings in grails the one would expect the following behavior:
all g.createLink and g.link by default do filtering of the optional attribute **params** based on Urlmappings.groovy logic. The rest of page params are ignored as irrelevant for the particular url.

Actually this doesn't happen. And the workaround is to provide all link params manually:

`<g:link action="action" controller="controller" params="[duplicated entries from url mappings]">my custom params link mapped in UrlMappings</g:link>`

Case the page params completelly passed as url params the one becomes a wierd url with custom mapping plus the rest of page params.

Answer (score 1):

There is no duplication. You need to define **what** parameters are defined in your path (just placeholders). If you generate a link you need to provide the **values** for those parameters. The values cannot be automatically derived.

The only thing you can do, is to beautify the notation using [namedMappings](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/theWebLayer.html#namedMappings). The advantage of this is, that you get at least an error message, if you have forgotten to pass in some required variables.

Or you define your own link `tag`, which automatically filters from the global `params` map.

Comment: In **UrlMappings** the params are placeholders, in the **params** object they are Map<k,v>. If the placeholders are equal to keys, what is the prolblem to replace them with matching params by default.

Comment: There would be too much collision. I am not sure which web-framework behaves like that.